# How to Flatten multiple GCS files (3NF table unloads) into one GCS file using GC Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have multiple files that are table unloads from a 3NF model loaded into Google Cloud Storage.  What are the recommended steps for joining/flattening into a single file for future use with BigQuery?

Can you point me to the best example(s) that match my use case?

Would it benefit me to load the individual files into BigQuery first?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow uses sources to transform files into collections of records. There currently isn't a built in source for 3NF files.

You can create your own [Custom Source](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sources) to process your files.

Since your data is in files you can use [FileBasedSource](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource) as the base class for your source.

Once you've written your source, you can build a pipeline which processes the records and then writes them to BigQuery using a [BigQuery Sink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io)

Comment: I was thinking that this might be a common pattern for exporting data from a relational DB into GCS and transforming via Data Flow into a flat format for BigQuery.  Have you seen a different way or can you think of a better way?

Comment: What part of the solution would you like to see improved? If you provide more details about what you are trying to do we might be able make specific recommendations. For example, when reading from a database a common question is whether to read the entire database and process/filter each record as necessary or to selectively import a subset of the data e.g. by running a query to select only those records you care about.  The solution will depend on your problem.